# interface reference is not getting instantiated with class instance in .net framework v4.5.2 c#

Tags: c#, interface, instance, .net-4.5

I am not able to instantiate an interface reference with class instance.

For e.g 
ClassesOnly.DLL (I have 2 interfaces and 1 class)

Now in `Main` method, I am trying below code but it is giving me error for invalid cast

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IfirstInterface ifObj=new FirstClassDLL();     
}

interface IfirstInterface
{
    void PrintId();
}
interface ISecondInterface:IfirstInterface 
{
    void SecondInterfaceMetod();   
}
public class FirstClassDLL:ISecondInterface,IfirstInterface
{
    public void PrintId()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in Print ID method from interface");
    }

    public void SecondInterfaceMetod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is the value of a ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these interfaces and class defined in a different assembly than the console applicaiton, if so try marking the interfaces as public!

Comment: Add exception full message to the question

Comment: Your code is working without any error http://rextester.com/YUMY86325

Comment: I am voting to close as unreproducable.

Comment: Interfaces should be public. Also, there is no need to make the class inherit from both interfaces because the ISecondInterface already inherits from IFirstInterface.